# how to parse key=val to a C program from command-line

Tags: c, getopt

I work in academic and I write my computation codes in C. I want to execute my program in a way like

```
$ ./foo.exe n=20 f=0.25 name=data.bin
```

I have done some reading about `getopt()` and `getsubopt()` but it seems to use these functions I have to organize command-line like

```
$ ./foo.exe -n 20 -f 0.25 -name data.bin
```

The key=val style is more suitable for my application since most of the parameters are numbers. Is it possible to extract key=val pattern from command-line arguments? Is there a library to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just because most of your parameters are numbers doesn't necessarily mean you should break [argument syntax conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't ever have spaces around the '=', then it's quite easy:

```
char letter;
float value;
if (sscanf(argv[i], "%c=%f", &letter, &value) == 2)
{
    // process option
}
else
{
    // argument doesn't match x=n pattern.
}
```